# numberOfSectionsInTableView is requested in/after viewDidLoad ONLY if tableview is empty

Tags: ios, uitableview

A simple tableviewController, empty. A modal that can be launched from a button. No data in the data source for the tableview, and no rows displayed.

I open the modal, use it to add an item, and return to the tableview controller. The tableview updates itself automatically, and the new row is displayed.

I add a second item. The table view does NOT update automatically.

I can tell by logging inside numberOfSectionsInTableView that even if I go to add the first item and cancel, the tableview refreshes - it asks for the number of sections, rows, and the cell to display (if there is one). But not if there is one pre-existing row in the table.

I've scoured my code but can't find anything that would cause the tableview to know when the first item is added, but none afterwards.

Any ideas?

EDIT - I have further narrowed my issue so will close this shortly and have posted a more specific question at [Why does an empty tableView check the number of sections but a non-empty one does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325829/when-and-why-does-a-tableview-check-the-number-of-sections)

Comment: If the tableview has found no data, it may be more aggressive in calling its dataSource. When you add data, meaning I believe that you have updated the data model backing the data source, do you issue an insertRow message, or ask the tableView to reload its data. Look at the class docs - there are a number of things you can do to tell the tableView the dataSource has changed.

Comment: I do neither so far - in fact, I can't. Assuming I want to animate the insertion, I need to insert a row. But, if the tableView has gone ahead and done this for me (which it is doing ONLY for the first row added), I will get a crash. This must be something suspect in my code - I have confirmed in other TVCs that numberOfSections isn't called automatically.

Comment: Funny - I just did a test the other day and it DID get called right away - empty table doing a test regarding another question here. It could be that when its in the background or hidden that the insert etc gets all screwed up. you could try "reloadData" and see if that works, if so get fancier later.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does an empty tableView check the number of sections but a non-empty one does not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325829/why-does-an-empty-tableview-check-the-number-of-sections-but-a-non-empty-one-doe)

Answer (score 1):

from Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> UITableView overrides the layoutSubviews method of UIView so that it
>   calls reloadData only when you create a new instance of UITableView or
>   when you assign a new data source.

maybe you are setting data source of table view after showing that modal? So at the second time data source does not changes and tableView does not update.

another key (I'm not sure about that) may be the showing of the modal first time. The method -addSubview for modal is causing -layoutSubviews.

Comment: These were great suggestions - unfortunately neither applied. Thanks though.