# Why does an empty tableView check the number of sections but a non-empty one does not?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have set up a demo application with a simple `UITableViewController` with no contents, but an 'Add' button in the toolbar. This launches a modal view controller which is again empty other than a 'cancel' button. The cancel button just tells its `delegate` (the `UITableViewController`) to dismiss the modal.

I then added an `NSLog` statement in the `UITableViewController`'s `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method.

Ordinarily, when the table view controller loads I see two calls to `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. When I open and dismiss the modal (which returns to the `UITableViewController`) I see no further calls to `numberOfSectionsInTableView`.

However, if I return `0` from `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, in addition to the two calls on display, I also see an additional numberOfSections call when the modal is dismissed.

This only happens when `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returns `0`, and I have added no additional code to my project besides that mentioned. This is easily verifiable by setting up a couple of controllers as I've described and modifying the result from `numberOfSectionsInTableView`.

My questions:

- Why is the `UITableView` calling `numberOfSectionsInTableView` on return from a modal view?
- Why is it only doing this if `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returns `0`?
- In addition to `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, the `UITableViewController` is also calling `cellForRowAtIndex:` when the modal is dismissed. In fact, it is attempting to display the new contents of its `dataSource`. How am I meant to manually animate a row insertion if the first row added is going to already be updated automatically? Shouldn't it be left to me to make sure that my `UITableView` is consistent with its `dataSource`?
- What property is the `UITableViewController` checking to know that there is one or more sections (and therefore ask my delegate how many sections)? It can't be `numberOfSectionsInTableView` itself, since I would see it called whenever I return from the modal, not only when numberOfSections = 0.

Comment: Could you post the sample code? Also I don't understand your 3rd and 4th questions, can you please rephrase them, and perhaps provide some more context? You didn't get into animations at all in your discussion.

Comment: I've added a demo and will also add the code shortly. I will also attempt to clarify my additional points. Thanks for cleaning up my sloppy question.

Comment: The code is a little long to post, so I linked to my demo project. I also attempted to clarify my questions as best I can. I am not asking for advice on animations, only pointing out that is the tableview is going to be refreshed automatically on display (for the first row only) I will not have an opportunity to insert the row myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`UITableViewController` docs:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> When the table view is about to appear the first time it’s loaded, the
>   table-view controller reloads the table view’s data... The
>   `UITableViewController` class implements this in the superclass method
>   `viewWillAppear:`

If you watch in the debugger, the **second** call upon app launch is from `UITableViewController`'s `viewWillAppear:` implementation - specifically the part referred to above, where `tableView` is sent the `reloadData` message.

Now, the **first** call to `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` on launch is also from `UITableViewController`'s implementation of `viewWillAppear:` but not directly from that implementation's call to `-[UITableView reloadData]`. I'm not sure what the first call is all about.

But, to your question, the call to `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` that happens when dismissing the modal has exactly the same call stack as the **second** call from `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:`. My hypothesis then is that `UITableView` interprets having zero sections as being in a state where it has not loaded at all. That does make some sense actually. I'd consider an "empty" table view to be one without any *rows*, but one without any *sections* seems almost "uninitialized" to me. Furthermore the `UITableViewDataSource` documentation implies `UITableView` has by default one section. Returning zero from this method would be inconsistent with that assumption of the docs as well.

Now, to your concern about animation - if you give the table an empty section to work with, you will be able to have full control over inserting the first row with whatever animation you'd like, and not be locked in to when you need to reload.

I think the moral of the story is, don't return zero sections unless you really, really need to for some reason. The title of your post refers to this table view being "empty" as well but I think it's clear the framework finds zero sections to not be empty but unloaded.

Hope this helps! And thanks for posting the sample project for me to play around with.

Comment: This is a great answer, many thanks. Two things tripped me up here. First, the Xcode-generated UITableViewController subclass returns 0, which I took to mean it was a sensible default (or placeholder, at least). Second, I am populating the number of sections from an array, so was returning array.count. I guess I need to just return MAX (1, array.count). I'm surprised I was unable to find other references to this elsewhere - perhaps populating sections from an array isn't so common. Thanks again for the thorough answer.

Comment: Some additional tips for anyone else doing this - if you implement titleForHeaderInSection, or any other section-related delegate, these all have to be updated to return nil in the special case where your sections datasource is empty. Otherwise instead of an empty list, the first section's header, footer, etc will be displayed, even though there are no rows.

Comment: You're welcome! And yeah that template has a couple of weird things about it - the `...cellForRow...` stub also leaves out instantiating cells. Good catch on the section header methods. It seems like there is some tension within the framework and the docs about how an empty table should work.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the delegate just couldn't believe its eyes. But seriously, since a table view has to have at least one section, passing 0 doesn't make any sense.  Why do it? You pass it an invalid argument and it gives you back a weird response. As to why it doesn't ask for number of sections when you pass 1, I think it's because it doesn't need to know at that point (coming back from the modal view controller) -- the table view has already been populated (if there were some data) and you haven't changed anything in the model, so it doesn't need to update.

I added a few lines to your example project to slide in a row each time you return from the modal view controller, which is what I think you're trying to do. I added an int property num for the return value of numberOfRowsInSection, added an array to populate the table, and a call to insertRowsAtIndexPaths from the modal view controller dismissal method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _num = 0;
    self.theData = @[@"one",@"two",@"three"];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                                          target:self
                                                                                          action:@selector(addRecipe)];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"# sections requested");
    //when 0, this fires on return from the modal. When 1, it does not.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"in numberOfRows in section");
    return _num;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"in cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.theData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)addRecipe
{
    //create the modal and suscribe for delegate notifications
    AddRecipeViewController *addRecipeController = [[AddRecipeViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    addRecipeController.delegate = self;

    //display the modal in a navigation controller
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addRecipeController];
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
}

- (void)addRecipeVC:(AddRecipeViewController *)addRecipeVC didAddRecipe:(NSString *)recipe
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    _num += 1;
    [self performSelector:@selector(addRow) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
}

-(void)addRow {
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_num-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tableview checks number of sections when it's populating the table view with data!
Since the table can be divided into sections, it has to know specifically how many sections to divide it into.
When you reload the data, the number of sections is also checked.

Because every time the table view has to take action in accessing either the data of the table, like what row you tapped, and in what section, or populating the data table, the number of sections has to be known!

Hope this helped!

Comment: Unfortunately not - I am aware of this behavior. I am trying to find out why an empty tableview would automatically check the number of sections on display, but one with 1 row or more would not. Thanks though.